# PySpark Merge dataframe and count values

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two different dataframes and i want to find out the intersection count between `m` columns from `df1` and `n` columns from `df2`. By intersection, I mean the number of unique values both the columns have in common. If df1 has 10 columns and df2 has 20 columns, then the number of intersection count I will get is 200. I am only using PySpark here.

In my case the data is huge and I ran the following codes

```
dict = {}
for a in df1.columns:
    i_u = df1.select(a).distinct()
    i_u = i_u.select(a).collect()
    for b in df2.columns:
            i_b = df2.select(b).distinct()
            i_b = i_b.select(b).collect()
            l = len(list(set(i_u) & set(i_b)))
            str = a + ","+b+","
            dict[str] = l
```

OR this code

```
dict = {}
for a in df1.columns:
    if not "." in a:
        for b in df2.columns:
            l = df1.join(df2, df1[a] == df2[b], how="inner")
            l = l.select(a).distinct().count()
            str = a + ","+b+","
            dict[str] = l
```

Or this

```
dict = {}
for a in df1.columns:
    i_u = df1.select(a).distinct()
    for b in df2.columns:
            a_u = df2.select(b).distinct()
            l = i_u.join(a_u, i_u[a] == a_u[b], how="inner").count()
            str = a + ","+b+","
            dict[str] = l
```

But in all these cases, the code is not fast enough as I am running two `for` loops. I want to create this dictionary or any representation of data where I have the two column names and their intersection count. I tried to use `cache` but still not good enough.

Dataset:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['red', 'green', 'blue','black','purple'], 'col2': ['one','two','three','nine','ten'], 'col3': ['val','2','sda','452','rww']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col9':['red', 'green', 'pink','orange','purple'], 'col10': ['seven','ten','nine','six','seven'], 'col11': ['val','2','dsrf','452','red']})

df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df1)
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df2)
```

the output dictionary should look something like this or any other format as long as there are column names and their count. it can be in any format, i just care about the output.

dict = {"col1,col9":3, "col1,col10": 0, "col1,col11":1, ...... }

Comment: Can you show a example of your dataframe ?

Comment: I wont be able to post the data but you can imagine dataset  as simple dataframe with every column containing simple strings. Think of datasets as two student dataset with information like name, ID, class, major, etc.

Comment: why not use pandas?

Comment: df1.union(df2).distinct()

Comment: you can show a sample containing 2 rows each and what the output should look like. It is difficult to visualize your requirement by looking at your code snippet

Comment: @ansev i cannot use pandas because the dataset is huge. imagine 100 columns to 100 columns with about 90k rows or more.

Comment: Updated with dataset example. @ansev

Comment: Updated with dataset example. @jjayadeep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the nested loops and letting Spark do it for you should significantly boost the performance. This requires two steps, expressed here as functions.

**First step:** collect the unique values in each column in an array and transpose the dataframe.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def unique_and_transpose(df):
    df = df.select([F.collect_set(col).alias(col) for col in df.columns])
    params = []
    for col in df.columns:
        params.extend([F.lit(col), col])
    return df.select(F.explode(F.create_map(*params)).alias('column', 'values'))
```

If all columns are guaranteed to be free of duplicate values, `F.collect_set(col)` can be replaced with `F.collect_array(col)`. Gathering only the unique values is not strictly necessary, but it may speed up the second step.

What this function does is best illustrated by an example:

```
>>> df1.show()
+------+-----+----+
|  col1| col2|col3|
+------+-----+----+
|   red|  one| val|
| green|  two|   2|
|  blue|three| sda|
| black| nine| 452|
|purple|  ten| rww|
+------+-----+----+

>>> unique_and_transpose(df1).show(3, False)
+------+---------------------------------+
|column|values                           |
+------+---------------------------------+
|col3  |[sda, 452, rww, 2, val]          |
|col1  |[blue, green, red, black, purple]|
|col2  |[nine, one, three, two, ten]     |
+------+---------------------------------+
```

**Second step:** create a Cartesian product of the transposed datasets and derive the quantity you seek.

```
def cross_relate(df1, df2):
    return df1.alias('df1').crossJoin(df2.alias('df2')).select(
        F.col('df1.column').alias('col_1'),
        F.col('df2.column').alias('col_2'),
        F.size(F.array_intersect('df1.values', 'df2.values')).alias('nvals')
    )
```

The Cartesian product does what the two nested loops do, but it only works row-wise, hence the need to first transpose the datasets.

With the help of those two functions, you can count the number of unique common values for each pair of columns like this:

```
df1_ut = unique_and_transpose(df1).cache()
df2_ut = unique_and_transpose(df2).cache()
df = cross_relate(df1_ut, df2_ut)
```

The result is:

```
>>> df.show()
+-----+-----+-----+
|col_1|col_2|nvals|
+-----+-----+-----+
| col3|col10|    0|
| col3| col9|    0|
| col3|col11|    3|
| col1|col10|    0|
| col1| col9|    3|
| col1|col11|    1|
| col2|col10|    2|
| col2| col9|    0|
| col2|col11|    0|
+-----+-----+-----+
```

You want a dictionary, so that's one more step:

```
res = {f"{row.col_1},{row.col_2}": row.nvals for row in df.collect()}

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(res)
{'col1,col10': 0,
 'col1,col11': 1,
 'col1,col9': 3,
 'col2,col10': 2,
 'col2,col11': 0,
 'col2,col9': 0,
 'col3,col10': 0,
 'col3,col11': 3,
 'col3,col9': 0}
```

Comment: In the `cross_relate` function, I am getting an error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention but data can also contain `None` values. But the error remains on the sample data in question too.

Comment: @rajatkabra, it's because `col()` was missing the module prefix. I had everything from `pyspark.sql.functions` imported, so the code worked for me. But it is better to keep the module prefix.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks for the help and this is extremely fast.

Comment: Glad to be of help.